# How to get an actionListener to interrupt another

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener, rcp

I have 3 different buttons with an actionListener for each. They all work, but I can't get a button to interrupt the others while they are executing their tasks? I want the task to be dropped when a button is pressed, so the new task will start immediately.

```
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event1)
            {
                int data1[] = {1100,1000,900,800,700,600,500,400,300,200,100}; 
                String labels2[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"};
                barGraph.changeDataWithEffect(data1, labels2);
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event2)
            {
                int data2[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}; 
                String labels2[] ={"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"};
                barGraph.changeDataWithEffect(data2, labels2);
            }
        });

        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event3)
            {
                int data3[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,50,40,30,20,10};
                String labels3[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"};
                barGraph.changeDataWithEffect(data3, labels3);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You mean when button 3 is pressed the other 2 shouldn't be working?

Comment: Say I press button 1. Then the changeDataWithEffect() gets called. Meanwhile i press button 2. At the moment it does nothing until the changeDataWithEffect() has been executed completely. I want it to stop immediately and start the new changeDataWithEffect()

Comment: Oooow like that. euhm let me think.

Comment: Read my edit! It has the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event3)
        {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int data3[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,50,40,30,20,10};
                    String labels3[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
                         "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
                        "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"};
                    barGraph.changeDataWithEffect(data3, labels3);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The first step is to have responsive buttons, that do long actions a bit later. Look into [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for management of runs.

---

If the changeDataWithEffect takes long, make several objects that do the work and with an atomic integer or reference to this hold a "current" object. By every step checking whether one is current, one can abort an old working object.

```
private class DataChanger {

     private boolean dead() {
         return active.get() != this;
     }
     void process() {
         ...
         if (dead()) return;
         ...
         if (dead()) return;
         ...
     }
}

private AtomicReferce<DataChanger> active = new AtomicReference<>(null);

public changeDataWithEffect(int[] data, String[] labels) {
    DataChanger current = new DataChanger(data, labels);
    SomeChangeDataHandler old = active.set(current);
    // Or old.kill();
    current.process();
 }
```

Comment: I implemented the piece of code but it doesn't do anything in my case? It does exactly the same as it did before?

Answer (score 2):

It does not make sense for one listener to 'interrupt' another, since whatever a listener does should *only take a moment.*  For a long running task, create a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and manipulate (start/stop etc.) that instance instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a boolean you can make it true at the button when you click it. And only let the others execute when it's false. So it won't work at the same time. But you will need multiple booleans. Or use `System.exit(0);`? Try it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Single Thread Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) and then enqueue the long running task into it. And then managed "checkForCancellation" if a task has priority.

Answer (score 1):

After carefully reading your answers (thank you very much indeed), and going through some tutorials, I tried a few things. None seemed to do exactly what i wanted though, but then I just approached the problem from a microprocessor's view and created my own interrupts that sets flags, instead of calling the method directly. This keeps the gui free to receive new inputs. It now works quite well :)